# UIView. What are the maximum bounds dimensions I can use?

Tags: iphone, uiview

Does anyone happen to know the maximum value for someView.bounds.size ? I'm creating a view hierarchy with where the accumulated bounding-box of all child views is equal to the root parent view.

Cheers,
Doug

Comment: I ran into limits over 2048px views in early iOS versions.  Does anyone know if this is still the case with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> Prior to iPhone OS 3.0, UIView
>   instances may have a maximum height
>   and width of 1024 x 1024. In iPhone OS
>   3.0 and later, views are no longer restricted to this maximum size but
>   are still limited by the amount of
>   memory they consume. Therefore, it is
>   in your best interests to keep view
>   sizes as small as possible. Regardless
>   of which version of iPhone OS is
>   running, you should consider using a
>   CATiledLayer object if you need to
>   create views larger than 1024 x 1024
>   in size.

In actuality, I was able to create UIViews and CALayers that were 2048 x 2048 in size on a standard iPhone / iPhone 3G in 2.x.  Anything above that just stopped rendering.

Comment: Thanks as always Brad. I'll look into CATiledLayer. One of the remaining bits of Cocoa I've been unclear is when I should implement at the CALayer level and when I should remain at the higher level UIView. Do you have any insight here? Thanks, Doug.

Comment: Performance-wise they are roughly the same.  You can do some more advanced animations with CALayers, but you can just perform these on the CALayer backing of a UIView.  The biggest reason I've found is Mac-iPhone cross-platform code, since CALayer's API is practically identical between the two platforms.  For more, see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447598/when-to-use-calayer-on-the-mac-iphone

Comment: i had some issues trying to render a big WKWebView hierarchy to an UIImage using contexts, finally if using a print formatter it worked by setting the page size according to the size i wanted to render, only in the first page..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a specific limit. I have created UIScrollViews that are hundreds of pages in width without any problem. Have you tried it and run into problems?

Paul

Comment: I am wondering about the maximum pixel dimensions for the contentView that a scrollView scrolls/zooms. What was the size in pixels of the pages you used?

Comment: I'm working on a book reader app. Some of the books are several hundred pages long, so that's 320 x 700 == 224000. What I'm saying is that I haven't seen a practical limit. I don't think it preallocates memory or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would not think there is a conceivable limit. Since the sizes are stored as floats, my guess would be that it is limited to `CGFLOAT_MAX` which is so large there is no need to worry about it.

Comment: Barry, my concern is instantiating a UIView - subclass there of - that blows past a fixed limit. Perhaps framebuffer size since hardware rendering is happening under the hood for everything on i(Phone|Pod).