# Maximum frame size of CALayer in iphone

Tags: iphone, calayer

I created a sublayer using [CALayer layer] and set its bounds to a underlying mapview which around a size of (8000,23000).

When i add the new layer to this view , i am able draw on this if 
the height of the layer is < =16000,whenever i extend to bigger hegiht.I am unable to draw on it.
Is there any specific max height for a CALayer.

Please let me how i can approach this problem.

Thanks in Advance.
Ratna

Answer (score 1):

From [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> Note: In iOS 2.x, the maximum size of
>   a UIView object is 1024 x 1024 points.
>   In iOS 3.0 and later, views are no
>   longer restricted to this maximum size
>   but are still limited by the amount of
>   memory they consume. It is in your
>   best interests to keep view sizes as
>   small as possible. Regardless of which
>   version of iOS is running, you should
>   consider tiling any content that is
>   significantly larger than the
>   dimensions of the screen.

Instead of using one giant CALayer I'd recommend you use [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) which is a subclass of CALayer.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493895/uiview-what-are-the-maximum-bounds-dimensions-i-can-use)