# UILabel view disappear when the height greater than 8192

Tags: ios, uilabel

Assigning large string to UILabel. And, adding this label into a scroll view.
The UILabel disappear when the UILabel height larger than 8192pt (which is 2^13).

Is this an iOS bug?

And should I use other implementation to render such amount of string?
Should I use table view with cell?

**UPDATE**

The code that will display the UILabel:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = rumor.displayText;
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 8192);
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

And the code that UILabel does disappear

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = rumor.displayText;
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 8193);
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: First of all, you need to show some of your code and screenshot

Comment: I read some day that a UIView should not be larger than 2048 pixel.

Comment: right.. http://blog.tofodo.com/2009/03/iphone-sdk-doesnt-like-long-texts.html

Comment: @dasdom The max height is _not_ 1024. The size is limited only by memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all - it doesn't have to be a bug. It is just undefined behavior. Note that with every component, there will be some upper size limit when the component stops working correctly . 8192 points seems to be a low limit but still it's about 8 times the iPad screen in portrait mode.

You are not supposed to make views that big. Note that `UIView`s are often rendered into memory and buffered, to make redrawing faster. With 8192 height, the buffer will have to be very big.

Splitting the text into several `UILabel`s (e.g. by paragraph) would definitely be an improvement.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1494496/669586

Answer (score 0):

**I ran into this same issue with UITextViews, and came up with a fairly effective solution.**

If you'd like to see it, check out my answer here!:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37147533/2155673

It should be fairly easily to adapt for UILabels.