# UITextView content disappears when number of lines set to 0

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, textview, uitextview

I am encountering a strange behaviour when using `UITextView` with a long text. In particular, when setting the `maximumNumberOfLines` of its `textContainer` to 0, the content disappears completely.

I have created a small test project to be sure there was nothing strange in my code that was causing it, and you can see it in the screenshots. In my project I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UIScrollView`, that contains a vertical `UIStackView`. The stack view contains a `UITextView` (the red title in the screenshots), another stackview containing a label, text view, button, and then other text views.

When the button is clicked I am setting `maximumNumberOfLines` to 0 (before it was 2), and the content just disappears. I've tried with and without animation and I have the same result. 
The disappearing seems to be related to the height of the final text, as if I use a smaller font, the content disappears only after setting much more text.

Any ideas why it could be happening?

For completeness, I am using Xamarin.iOS, and [here](https://pastebin.com/tn8Z7EuP)
 is my ViewController.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Are you setting a Height constraint on your text view? If not, do you have scrolling disabled?

Comment: @DonMag Scrolling is disabled, no height constraint on the text view.

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like you have it set up correctly... you said you *"created a small test project"* --- can you share that project?

Comment: @DonMag I have edited my question and added a link to a paste of my view controller at the end of my question. And I realised I forgot to say I'm using Xamarin. Nevertheless I suppose it's not too easy to understand. And sorry for the not so clear and nice code, but it was just for a test ;)

Comment: Are you using `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` because you need it to be editable at some point?

Comment: @DonMag No, it will never be editable, but the text view seems to be more appropriate because it should be the most appropriate to display large amounts of text

Comment: `UITextView` would only be more appropriate if it was going to be editable, or scrollable. Since you're doing neither, I'd suggest going with labels. It would simplify things quite a bit, since you can set the `.numberOfLines` directly on the label, instead of dealing with `NSTextStorage` / `NSLayoutManager` / `NSTextContainer` (which may be the root of the issue anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Content disappears because your text is too large for a `UIView` object to show. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1494496/8354952) we know that, actually `UIView` has a maximum height and width limited by the amount of memory they consume.

In my test if we don't set too much characters to the `textView`(remove some `textView.Text += textView.Text;`), the content will show. And I also tested that on `UILabel`, so does it. Because they all inherit from `UIView`.

If you do want to show so many strings, try to enable the textView's `ScrollEnabled`. Do not let the textView's Bounds exceed the maximum limit. You can try to add the Height and Width Constraints when you want to expand the textView:

```
var textViewContraints = new NSLayoutConstraint[]
{
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(textView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1f, 700),
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(textView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1f, 500)
};

UIView.AnimateNotify(1.2d, () =>
{
    if (!buttonExpanded)
    {
        textView.ScrollEnabled = true;
        textView.TextContainer.MaximumNumberOfLines = 0;
        textView.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        textView.SizeToFit();
        textView.AddConstraints(textViewContraints);
        expandButton.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((nfloat)(Math.PI / 2.0f));

        textView.Text = "r" + textStr;
        textView.Text = textView.Text.Substring(1);
    }
    else
    {
        textView.ScrollEnabled = false;
        foreach (NSLayoutConstraint constraint in textView.Constraints)
        {
            textView.RemoveConstraint(constraint);
        }
        textView.TextContainer.MaximumNumberOfLines = 3;
        textView.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        expandButton.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(0f);

        textView.Text = textStr;
    }

    scrollView.LayoutIfNeeded();
    buttonExpanded = !buttonExpanded;
}, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is definitely a good thing to know ;)