# What is the best technique to implement a permanent animated background in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I need to add a background where random clouds comes from the sides. This effect need to be almost in every screen of the app. I tried using `animateWithDuration` with `UIImageView`s but it consumes a lot of battery, and when I am on some screens with other extra animations, this animations look jerky.

Also tried using `.gif` and videos as background:

[Video as background](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2#.v0kc0sjum)

But they are to heavy, since it has to be a long video in order to make it look like the clouds appears in random intervals. And also consumes a lot of resources.

Are there other ways to make this effect, like a lightweight animation technique?

Comment: take a look at [this library](https://github.com/Boris-Em/NightView) , it doesn't add clouds but stars :D you can take a look at how it is structured in order to get an idea

Comment: A high performance implementation of animation can be found at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21079559/763355

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your best bet would be to use a CALayer on your UIViews, it should be more lightweight than the UIImage solution.

Comment: I tried it just now, unfortunately, I have the same results. And one problem with this solution is that CALayer can't be rendered offscreen (To make the clouds enter from the sides)

Comment: How are you drawing the clouds?  You create the clouds as sublayers using images, and then just move them about.

Comment: I was creating a CALayer setting its `content` with a `[UIImage imageNamed:@"cloud"].CGImage`. I found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686873/ios-should-i-add-uiviews-or-calayers-for-animation. It says there is almost no difference between both approachs :(

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it to be that intensive, are your cloud images optimised for the resolution you're using?

Comment: In my case, I only have 8 clouds. And when any of the clouds dissapears from screen it should start the animation again. And yes, they are optimized for the resolution.