# What means layer and not layer in customviews?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

if i create a custom view class that inherit from the `UIView` Class i can access properties with the keyword `layer.` for example `layer.cornerRadius = 10` and for example the background with `backgroundColor = (Color Literal)` WITHOUT `layer.`

Why? What means `layer` and when i use it and when not?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622436-layer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a UIView and a CALayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826306/what-are-the-differences-between-a-uiview-and-a-calayer)

Comment: Some properties like the backgroundColor and more are exposed for access and/or modification by the class UIView. Some are not, and can be accessed by the properties of the associated layer for the view, such as cornerRadius.